# Getting around SNS API call limits to publish

Tags: amazon-sns

I need to publish a unique message to potentially thousands of device endpoints simultaneously.

The message is unique so I cant group the endpoints in to topics...

Although I cant find any documentation, it seems that SNS limits to only 10 concurrent API publish requests.

More than 10 concurrent requests returns

```
RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp 54.239.24.226:443: i/o timeout
```

And then seems to block my IP from further requests for a short time...

I was planing to have the whole app backend to be "serverless" which would mean that there would be a scheduled task in Lambda to make the calls to SNS publish...

1000 SNS publish requests / 10 concurrent = 100 batches...This would mean it would take 100 * x seconds to process all the messages which would reach the API gateway and Lambda timeout limits (and would also add to the costs)

Is there a good way around these limits. A increase in allowed concurrent API calls would be nice...

Comment: Try contacting aws support - they can raise most usage limits.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon SNS [does not enforce a rate limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_sns) for Publish calls. Occasionally, SNS will throttle requests but the service will [respond with HTTP 400](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/CommonErrors.html) and an AWS SNS request ID.

The error message you posted looks like something upstream between you and the SNS endpoint is rate limiting your calls. Check if there is a proxy or firewall between you and the SNS endpoint, or talk to your network administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You can request additional limit increases here:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/cases#/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-sns

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something like this before and the solution was launching tens of t2.micro or t2.nano instances. Because there is also a limit about the requests that you can make from ec2 to aws.

Comment: It's going to be heaps cheaper to ask AWS to increase the limit, spinning up EC2's defeats the point of using a managed notification service.

Answer (score 0):

AWS SNS quotas for publishing a messages ranges between 30K transactions/sec to 300 based on if its fifo and which region. If it's fifo there is a 10mb/sec limit so that maybe what is limiting the publishes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sns.html